# Viewing sharepoint documnets in Salesforce using Files Connect

Tags: visualforce, oauth2, lightning-connect, auth, external-app

I want to view my Sharepoint documnets in salesforce using "**File Connect**" introduced in Winter15 release for connecting to External Data source but i am facing a problem to connect to  sharepoint. I have used the follwing link for Set Up **Salesforce Files Connect** :

- http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/api_cti/release-notes/rn_chatter_files_connect_setup.htm
  and followed the steps below :

1) First, enable Files Connect, and let users access related external data sources

```
  a) Enable Files Connect for your organization.
  b) Let users access Files Connect data sources.
```

2) For cloud-based data sources, create an authentication provider, and then define the source

```
 a) Create a SharePoint Online authentication provider.
 b) Define a SharePoint Online external data source for Files Connect.
```

But when completing the step2 b) and clicking on Start Authentication Flow on Save as checked  and saving it takes me to sharepoint login page and when logged in to sharepoint following error occurs:

[image]

I have checked lots of sites but unable to correct fix this issue.If anyone has knowledge please,please share it with me as soon as possible .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As part of step 2, you need to configure the redirect_uri parameter. See [this](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_files_connect_sp_online_auth.htm&language=en_US) link which clearly states

> Redirect URL— Enter the Callback URL you copied when creating the
>   Authentication Provider in Salesforce.

If this does not match the value that was specified while creating an auth provider in Salesforce, it would result in the error that you are seeing.